# MOSFET in cadence is symmetric? Source and drain don't really matter diagramatically

Tags: cadence

I am doing an OTA in cadence and I accidentally was using an upside down NMOS MOSFET. What I mean by that is that considering lower voltages are on the bottom of your circuit, then the arrow that goes out of the nmosfet (the source) was on top instead of on the bottom.

It turns out my simulations are almost exactly identical to the corrected case where the diagram's source is on the bottom.

So my question is: does it really matter which terminal is used for source and drain? Maybe it does because source and drain terminals are doped differently but maybe the mosfet is completely symmetric.

In the image look at transistor M14 on the right side.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your design? How did you connect the body terminal of the MOSFET?

Comment: Yes. I have done this now.

Comment: Body of the nMOS goes to ground because of the fabrication process I use. This wouldve been a problem for PMOS but luckily i didnt flip the pmos transistors.

Answer (score -1):

> Does it really matter which terminal is used for source and drain?

Yes.

The actual MOSFET is symmetrical operationally.

ie the channel is a voltage controlled two-quadrant resistor that conducts with either D-S polarity as long as appropriate Vgs is applied.

HOWEVER, in almost all practical devices* there is an 'intrinsic" Drain-Source diode biased so as to NOT conduct when the FET is used with the normal polarity.
If you swap frain and source terminals you can still turn on / enhance an NMOS device by applying a positive voltage on the gate relative to the source.
You CANNOT enhance the device by applying a voltage to gate relative to drain.

*Integrated circuits using a non conductive substrate such as Saphire on Silicon do not have intrinsic body diodes.  You MAY be able to buy discrete devices where the substrate and source are brought out separately but in about 100% of real world devices the source and substrate are electrically connected internally. Having the source and substrate not connected complicates control of the device.

Comment: Cadence is mainly (so far as I know) used by IC designers, so it most likely treats the body as an independent 4th terminal, which can be connected as you like. It wouldn't assume the body is tied to the source like we generally do when designing with discrete components.

Comment: You connect the body to whatever terminal you want. All nmos devices were connected to ground so this issue is not a concern. Also I accidentally flipped my NMOS device not my PMOS.

Comment: Since the asker is talking about FETs on ICs, I think it's better to call it drain-body and source-body diodes, as the source and body are not connected here.

Comment: Low voltage 4-terminal (G,S,D,B) FETs are usually symmetrical. However this is not required and some technologies have different structures for Drain vs. Source (this helps with a hot carrier injectio and breakdown votlage). High votlage MOSFETs are always assymetical (because the drain-gate can withstand a higher V than the G-S). Usually discrete FETs also have the bulk tied to the source, so of course these are not reversible.